# linux + how to rename the current volume group

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, disk-volume

we have redhat linux 7.2 version

my current partition is

```
/dev/mapper/rh7-home   36G   33M   26G   1% /home
```

so how to replace the volume group from:

```
/dev/mapper/rh7-home   36G   33M   26G   1% /home
```

to:

```
/dev/mapper/rh7-var   36G   33M   26G   1% /var
```

the reason for change is because the wrong volume name - **rh7-home** that should be **rh7-var**

so I need to rename the volume name and then umount /home and mount the right name to /var

- for now /var is local folder and I want to mount /var to the volume

Comment: Please explain a lot better what  you want to do (and optimally: why).

Comment: I update the question with more details , hope its clear now -:)

Comment: Headline is misleading: You are trying to rename a _logical volume_, not a _volume group_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to rename a *logical volume*, not a *volume group*!

Try:

```
lvrename rh7 home var
```

The logical volume **may not be mounted at this moment**.